# python class : when I call the class methods, it always output a "None" within the result

Tags: python, class, methods

I am writing a code to document an employee system, the class can print full name, email:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self,first,last):
        self.first=first
        self.last=last
        
    def fullname(self):
        print('{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last))
    def email(self):
        print('{}.{}@email.com'.format(self.first,self.last))

emp_1=Employee('John','Smith')
emp_1.first='Jim'

print(emp_1.first)
print(emp_1.email())
print(emp_1.fullname())
```

Output is like this:

[image: output]

I don't understand why when I call methods (`email()`, `fullname()`), I have a `None` within the output?

The output is:

```
Jim
Jim.Smith@email.com
None
Jim
Smith
None
```

Comment: i didn't look at the screenshot. you need to `return` something from those methods to see it in the output.

Comment: You're confusing what's being printed with what data is returned from each function. `print` is just *for you* to visualize what a value is. It has **nothing** to do with how data is transferred or is flowing through the computer.

Comment: When you don't return anything from a function/method the standard return value is `None`. So you have 2 choices: (1) Return the strings without printing and then print the returns. (2) Print the strings in the methods but don't print the returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the method call inside a `print` function. So it will try to print the value which is returned from the method. Since you are not returning anything from the method, it prints `None`.

You can always return the value instead of printing them inside. Example.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    def fullname(self):
        # just printing the name will not return the value.
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def email(self):
        # same, use a return statement to return the value.
        return '{}.{}@email.com'.format(self.first, self.last)


emp_1 = Employee('John', 'Smith')
emp_1.first = 'Jim'

print(emp_1.first)
print(emp_1.email())  # print what is returned by the method.
print(emp_1.fullname())
```

It will give a proper output like

```
Jim
Jim.Smith@email.com
Jim Smith
```